# How can dB/dt be defined as a function of the velocity of a permanent magnet (with a known B value) moving towards and then through a conducting loop?

Tags: electromagnetism

Course tutorial questions on faradays law often give numerous examples of rates of changing angle between the A and B vector, or rate of changing Area. However for a dB/dt case you are always given dB/dt in Teslas per second.

If you only know the velocity of a permanent magnet, moving towards a conducting loop, how can dB/dt be written as a function of velocity or position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look back at [the law itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).  It says that the electromotive force $\mathcal{E}$ is given by the rate of change of the magnetic flux $\Phi_B$.  It's not written directly in terms of the area $A$ or the magnetic field $\vec{B}$; it's written in terms of the flux $\Phi_B$, which is kind of the product of the two.  Technically, the flux is given by
\begin{equation}
  \tag{1}
  \Phi_B = \iint_{\Sigma(t)} \vec{B}(\vec{r}, t) \cdot d\vec{A}(\vec{r}, t),
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma(t)$ is some surface bound by your loop, and $d\vec{A}$ is a differential area element, which might be changing in time.

Now the details of that expression may be a little distracting, but basically it's just the magnetic field dotted into the area.  So the hand-wavy version of this is
\begin{equation}
  \Phi_B \approx \vec{B} \cdot \vec{A}.
\end{equation}
(Just remember that if this product changes much over your surface, you'll eventually need to integrate over the surface to get the real answer.)  Faraday's Law just says
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{E} = -\frac{d\Phi_B} {dt}.
\end{equation}
Next, we can use the hand-wavy expression and the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) to write
\begin{equation}
  \mathcal{E} \approx -\frac{d\vec{B}}{dt} \cdot \vec{A} - \vec{B} \cdot \frac{d\vec{A}}{dt}.
\end{equation}
Apparently, you've only been seeing problems where the second term is important — meaning that the magnetic field didn't change in time, only the area, so $d\vec{B}/dt=0$.  Now you're seeing one where the first term matters too.  And if they've made things easy on you, you'll have $d\vec{A}/dt=0$ for this problem too.

If you're doing this properly, using the real definition of $\Phi_B$ given in equation (1), things get bit complicated with remembering limits, and total versus partial derivatives, etc.  The wikipedia page I linked above does a good job explaining those details.  But this is the basic idea.

Comment: For this example dA/dt = 0, so no worries there.

I can follow what you are explaining with your use of eq.1

This example is a practical, I have a permanent magnet with flux density value B. I know this because its given to me by the manufacturer of the magnet.

I have a conducting loop, area constant and known. For a particular scenario I know the velocity of the magnet in the direction of the area vector of the surface for each time step as it moves towards the conducting loop and all the way through it, using this information is it possible to define dB/dt? if so how?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but very complicated, and it depends on exactly what the manufacturer means by "flux density $B$".  You need to know the value of $\vec{B}$ at each point of your surface, so you basically need a formula, and that will depend on things like the shape of the magnet.  For example, [this manufacturer](https://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/How-do-you-calculate-the-magnetic-flux-density) provides explicit formulas for a few basic shapes — but even then only along the symmetry axis.  So...

Comment: Take their sphere, for example.  (This is nice, because it's totally symmetric, which means the formula works everywhere.)  The field strength depends on distance $z$.  If $z$ is changing in time, then $B$ is changing in time.  In particular, if I differentiate their formula, $dB/dt = -3 B \frac{dz}{dt} / (R+z)$.  You said you know the magnet's velocity, so you know $dz/dt$, which means you can calculate $dB/dt$ from this formula.  But remember, this formula only gives you the radial component, so you need to dot that into the area element and integrate.  Things get complicated quickly.